# how to show custom list view record in edit text

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a custom list view with two text view and one edit text and under the custom list view there is one edit text(textPostalAddress),what i want to do is that when user enter the value in edit text of custom list view  at that time i want add that record in edit text which is below the list view ,when user again enter the value that value also show with previous value in edit text..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
ArrayList<Candy> myArrList;
EditText text;
EditText et;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     myArrList = new ArrayList<Candy>();
     ListView lisView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);       
     myArrList.add(new Candy("Butterscotch", "10"));
     myArrList.add(new Candy("Birthday Cake", "100"));
     myArrList.add(new Candy("Black Crunch", "102"));
     myArrList.add(new Candy("Industrial Chocolate", "200"));
     myArrList.add(new Candy("Coffee Molasses Chip", "500"));      
     lisView1.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter(this));}
     public class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
     {
     private Context context;
     public CountryAdapter(Context c)
     {
        context = c;
     }
     public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return myArrList.size();
        }
     public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
        }
     public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
        }
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mmnue, null);
            }
        // ColID
        TextView txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm);
        txtID.setText(myArrList.get(position).getName() +".");
        // ColCode
        TextView txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rat);
        txtCode.setText(myArrList.get(position).getRate());
        text = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
        text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after){}
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
        String rk=myArrList.get(position).getName()+","+s+","+myArrList.get      (position).getRate();
                     et.setText(rk);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello"+s+""+myArrList.get
                      (position).getName()+""+myArrList.get(position).getRate(), 50).show();
                                   }
                             });
                     return convertView;}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get records from edittext and add it to the arraylist. then call lisView1.invalidate(); to update that record in the listview

Comment: i want to show record of custom list to edit text which is below the list view,i don't want to update my list view.

Comment: in onTextChanged Listener of 'text' add et.append(s.toString)

Comment: ok it work but there is one problem when i enter the value in edit text just like "12" then it show record in edit text like "1","2",I want to show record like "12"

Comment: try it on afterTextChanged()

Answer (score 0):

`EditText` is difficult to use as an item in each `ListView` row. A solution in my mind that you should use a `Button` as item instead of `EditText` and by clicking on this button open an `AlertDialog` containing an `EditText`, enter value in edittext press Ok and append it on the `Edittext` outside of `listview` for example in your adapter's `getView` method do something like below:

```
Button btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn); 
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

                showAlertDialog();

}

});

private void showAlertDialog() 
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        EditText input = new EditText(context);

        builder.setTitle("Enter any value");

        builder.setView(input);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                et.append(input.getText().toString()+"  ");

            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```